# Fortran Error - attempt to call a routine with argument number three as a real(kind =1) when procedure was required

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran project linked to various subroutines, which are called from the main program. Variables are passed using modules. I can compile the code without any error. When I run the code, during the subroutine call i get an error "attempt to call a routine with argument number three as a real(kind =1) when procedure was required. I am not sure where i am going wrong. Can someone point out the error? Your help is very much appreciated. The error appears when the subroutine 'ncalc' is called inside the loop

```
program partbal

use const
use times
use density
use parameters
use rateconst
use ploss

implicit none

integer :: i
real :: nclp_init, ncl2p_init, ncln_init, ne_init
real :: ncl_init, ncl2_init, Te_init, neTe_init

open (10,file='in.dat')
read (10,*) 
read (10,*) pressure
read (10,*)
read (10,*) P, pfreq, duty
read (10,*)
read (10,*) nclp_init, ncl2p_init, ncln_init, Te_init, Ti

pi   = 3.14159265
R    = 0.043
L    = 0.1778
Al   = 2*pi*R*R
Ar   = 2*pi*R*L
V    = pi*R*R*L
S    = 0.066
e    = 1.6e-19
me   = 9.1e-31
mCl  = 35.5/(6.023e26)
mCl2 = 2*mCl
k    = 1.3806e-23
vi   = (3*Ti*e/(53.25/6.023e26))**0.5

ncl2_init    = pressure*0.1333/(1.3806e-23*298)/2
ncl_init     = ncl2_init
ne_init      = nclp_init + ncl2p_init - ncln_init

tot_time    =    1/(pfreq*1000)
off_time    =    duty*tot_time
npoints     =    10000
dt          =    tot_time/npoints

neTe_init   =    ne_init*Te_init

t_step = 0
call kcalc(Te_init)
call param(nclp_init, ncl2p_init, ncln_init, ne_init, ncl_init,ncl2_init, Te_init, Ti)

do i = 1, npoints, 1

t_step = i*dt + t_step
if (t_step > 0 .and. t_step <= 500) then
  Pabs = 500
else if (t_step > 500) then
  Pabs = 0
end if

if (i <= 1) then
    call ncalc(ne_init, ncl_init, ncl2_init, nclp_init, ncln_init, ncl2p_init)
    call powerloss(ne_init, ncl_init, ncl2_init, Pabs, neTe_init)
    Te = neTe/ne
    call kcalc(Te)
    call param(nclp, ncl2p, ncln, ne, ncl, ncl2, Te, Ti)
else 
    call ncalc(ne, ncl, ncl2, nclp, ncln, ncl2p)
    call powerloss(ne, ncl, ncl2, Pabs, neTe)
    Te = neTe/ne
    call kcalc(Te)
    call param(nclp, ncl2p, ncln, ne, ncl, ncl2, Te, Ti)  
end if


!open( 70, file = 'density.txt' )
!open( 80, file = 'Te.txt')
!do i = 1, 1001, 1
!  np(i) = ncl2p(i) + nclp(i)
!write (70, *) ncl(i), ncl2(i), ncl2p(i), nclp(i), np(i), ncln(i), ne(i)
!close(70)
!write (80, *) Te(i), phi(i)
!close(80)
!end do
end do

end program partbal

subroutine ncalc(n_e, n_cl, n_cl2, n_clp, n_cln, n_cl2p)

use parameters
use const
use density
use rateconst
use times

implicit none

real :: n_e, n_cl, n_cl2, n_clp, n_cln, n_cl2p

 nclp    =  (((kCliz*n_e*n_cl)+((kpair+kdisiz)*n_e*n_cl2)-(5e-14*n_clp*n_cln)-(S*n_clp/V)-((hlclp*Al+hrclp*Ar)*n_clp*ubclp))*dt)+n_clp
 ncl2p   =  (((kCl2iz*n_e*n_cl2)-(5e-14*n_cl2p*n_cln) - (((hlcl2p*Al + hrcl2p*Ar)*n_cl2p*ubcl2p)/V)-(S*n_cl2p/V))*dt)+n_cl2p
 ncln    =  ((((katt+kpair)*n_e*n_cl2)-(5e-14*n_clp*n_cln)-(5e-14*n_cl2p*n_cln)-(kdet*n_e*n_cln)-(S*n_cln/V)-(taun*(Al+Ar)/V))*dt)+n_cln
 ne      =  ncl2p+nclp-ncln
 ncl     =  ((((2*kdis+katt+kdisiz)*n_e*n_cl2)-(kCliz*n_e*n_cl)+(5e-14*n_cl2p *n_cln)+(2*5e-14*n_clp*n_cln)+ (kdet*n_e*n_cln) - (300*n_cl) + ((hlclp*Al + hrclp*Ar)*n_clp*ubclp/V)-(S*n_cl/V))*dt)+n_cl
 ncl2    =  ((n_cl2(1) + (5e-14*n_cl2p*n_cln) - ((kCl2iz+kdis+katt+kpair+kdisiz)*n_e*n_cl2) + (0.5*300*n_cl) + ((hlcl2p*Al + hrcl2p*Ar)*n_cl2p*ubcl2p/V)-(S*n_cl2/V))*dt)+n_cl2

return

end subroutine ncalc
```

Comment: You have some lines that are longer than 132 characters.  That violates the standard and can cause puzzling problems.

Answer (score 2):

In the line in subroutine ncalc immediately before the return statement, you have a reference to `n_cl2(1)` very early in the right hand side of the assignment statement.  `n_cl2` has not been declared as an array, therefore the compiler assumes that it must be a reference to a function that takes a single default integer argument.  Because n_cl2 is a dummy argument, the it then expects you to provide a function for the corresponding actual argument when the routine is called.

(How your compiler manages to compile the preceding references to n_cl2 is a bit of a mystery -  I suspect this error violates the syntax rules and hence you should see some sort of compile time diagnostic.)

Given you are using modules, it seems odd that you have not placed the ncalc routine in a module.  If you did so, the error would probably become a compile time error rather than a runtime.